# Overloadding constructors

Tags: java, constructor, this

```
private int a = 2;
public A(int x) {
    a = x*2;
} 
public A() {
    this(5);
}
public int test() {
    return a;
}
public static void main(String argv[]) {
    A a1 = new A();
    System.out.println(a1.test());
}
```

Hey guys, I'm new to Java and this is a question for my mock test. The output is 10, which I thought should be 5. Please help! Much appreciate!

Comment: please Format your code properbly

Comment: Please format your code more readably. You have plenty of vertical space - use it! Now, why do you think the answer should be 5? You're calling `new A()`, which will call the `A(int)` constructor with an argument of 5... and then that constructor is doubling the value to 10.

Comment: If you use a Debugger, you will see what is happend

Comment: 5 is passed to `A(int)` so you get 10, which you would be able to see in your debugger.

Comment: I have a hard time to understand how one could think that the result would be 5 ...

Comment: I think your "mock test" is telling you that you should spend some **serious** time looking in the absolute basics of the Java language.

Comment: You know you can accept an answer by following the steps here > http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 4):

You main invokes the `A()` constructor, which calls the `A(int x)` (by the statement `this(5);`). Therefore `a` is assigned 10 (`a = x*2;` where `x` is 5).

Answer (score 0):

Well what happens is:

```
A a1 = new A();
```

this uses the **public A()** constructor so it goes to:

```
public A(){
    this(5);
}
```

this will now call the **public A(int x)** constructor 
and x will be equal to 5 so this will be called:

```
public A(5) {
    a = 5 * 2;
}
```

Therefore:

```
a = 5 * 2;
a = 10;
```

So a will be 10.

So this:

```
System.out.println(a1.test());
```

Will call the test method on the a1 object, which returns the integer a of a1, which we found out is 10.

So essentially this happens:

```
System.out.println(10);
```

So the output is 10.

This is essentially what you will see if you use debug mode (which every IDE has).